# React native app is blocking push notifications from other apps

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification

I have react native app and when its installed on ios I'm not receiving any notifications from that app or from any other apps. When I delete my app I receive ALL push notifications that i should be receiving
I have no clue how is it possible, but it looks like my app is blocking notifications from another apps

Any ideas what it can be and how I can fix it?

Comment: Would love to know if you figured out the reason for this. Could be a great feature for “focus mode” in certain apps.

Comment: Were you able to solve this ? Having the same issue with react-native-onesignal. Although unsure if thats causing it.

Comment: We're experiencing the same thing intermittently. Were you able to figure out what's causing it.